# Low-Contrast Color Scheme in xxxterm config file?

Tags: browser

I know I can set a "Low-Contrast Color Scheme" with the "s" button in xxxterm.

**Q:** but how can I set this Low-Contrast Color Scheme to be default? (in the .xxxterm.conf) So that "s" key doesn't need to be pressed.

UPDATE: Using:

```
userstyle_global = 1
```

produces this:

[image]

in ~/.xxxterm.conf. xxxterm version: 1:1.10.0-1 (according to dpkg)

Comment: That's weird, it must be a new feature (I have `1.11.3`). Is upgrading an option?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add this line to your `~/.xxxterm.conf` file:

```
userstyle_global = 1
```

From `man xxxterm`

```
 xxxterm tries to open the user specific file, ~/.xxxterm.conf.  If that file
 is unavailable, it then uses built-in defaults.

 The format of the file is <keyword> = <setting>.  For example:

       http_proxy = http://127.0.0.1:8080

 Enabling or disabling an option is done by using 1 or 0 respectively.

[...]

       userstyle_global            When enabled new tabs will automatically
                                   be displayed in low contrast mode.
```

Comment: hey Thanks! I created the ~/.xxxrc file, added the line you mentioned, but it didn't worked for some reason.. ps.: I have a ~/.xxxterm.conf file

Comment: @gaskopeter sorry, my bad, I meant `~/.xxxterm.conf`. Answer edited.

Comment: Thanks! but it still looks bad.. :\ I updated the question